# Passing values from a php page to a modal from other page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, modal-dialog

I'm trying to edit a post using this snippiet of from my query.php page:

```
echo '<button type="submit"  onclick="openModal(this)" id="btn-edit"
name="edit" value='.$postID.'></button>';


function openModal(id)
{
    var editpost = id.value;
        $.ajax({
            url:"query.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{ editpost : editpost },
            success:function(data)
            { //
            },
            error: function () {//
            }
        });
    $('#edit').modal('show');
}
```

The function to get the data from the post selected is on the same php page. This is the code:

```
if(isset($_POST['editpost'])) 
{
    session_start();
    $editpostid = $_POST['editpost'];

    if($editpostid != "")
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE PostId = '" . $editpostid . "'";
    }

    if($sql != "")
    {
        $qry = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($qry) > 0) 
        {
            foreach($qry as $row)
            {
                $_SESSION['editpostdesc'] = $row['PostDesc'];
                $_SESSION['editpostfile'] = $row['PostFile'];
                $_SESSION['editpostid'] = $row['PostId'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the modal is on the other page (main page). I want to get the data of the post and display it on the modal, so I tried using `$_SESSION`. Yes, I got the data and was able to display it on the modal, *but the problem is when I try to edit another post, the first value assigned to the session cannot be replaced*. Is there is any other way that I can pass the values without using session? I'm really running out of ideas, I'm just starting my first web project.

Comment: what output do you want...?

Comment: @AravinthE a modal which shows the value of the sessions, friend.

Answer (score 0):

if you get multiple row means this methods will worked...

```
if(isset($_POST['editpost'])) 
{
    session_start();
    $editpostid = $_POST['editpost'];

    if($editpostid != "")
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE PostId = '" . $editpostid . "'";
    }

    if($sql != "")
    {
        $qry = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($qry) > 0) 
        {
            foreach($qry as $row)
            {
                $res[] = array(
                                'editpostdesc' => $row['PostDesc'],
                                'editpostfile' => $row['PostFile'],
                                 'editpostid'  => $row['PostId']
                               ); 
            }


        }
    }
}
```